# How get groupId of the Kafka listener in java?

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-el

I have a Kafka listener where I am setting the group id with the SpEL (Spring Expression) to generate the randomly generated unique id for each run/instance. I need to get hold of this group id for logging and monitoring purpose. Any suggestions?

Comment: The logs should already be printing `ConsumerConfig` section with the group id

Comment: `KafkaUtils.getConsumerGroupId()`.

Comment: thanks @GaryRussell ...i upgraded the spring-kafka version and was able to get the group id

Comment: meanwhile I was also able to get the ConsumerConfig by injecting KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry in my listener class ...thanks @OneCricketeer for the input on ConsumerConfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `KafkaUtils.getConsumerGroupId()` from the `org.springframework.kafka.support` package.

```java
/**
 * Get the group id for the consumer bound to this thread.
 * @return the group id.
 * @since 2.3
 */
public static String getConsumerGroupId() {...}
```

[See the KafkaUtils docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/api/org/springframework/kafka/support/KafkaUtils.html#getConsumerGroupId()) for more details.